# WHERE clause with nested multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, where-clause, multiple-conditions

I want to retrieve data with conditions in `WHERE` clause.
Here is my table something look like:

```
Name   Location    Age
----------------------
AAA     Bhuj       24
BBB     Mumbai     22
CCC     Bhuj       18
DDD     Bhuj       27
EEE     Mumbai     26
```

My condition in `WHERE` clause is:
`if location = 'Bhuj' then Age>20 else if location = 'Mumbai' then Age>25`

I am trying this code to achieve this:

```
SELECT * FROM testing
WHERE 
CASE Location WHEN 'Bhuj' THEN Age>20
              WHEN 'Mumbai' THEN Age>25
END;
```

This code works fine for MySQL ([see this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6120e/1)) but does not work for SQL Server ([see this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6120e/1)) and giving the following error:

> Incorrect syntax near '>'.: SELECT * FROM testing WHERE case Location When 'Bhuj' then Age>20 When 'Mumbai' then Age>25 end

Any suggestion?

Comment: Don't see any reason to downvote the question. Upvoted :)

Comment: @NitinGoyal My actual query is different and complex. Where I have to use `CASE` statement. I shown it simply here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM testing 
WHERE  
Age > case Location When 'Bhuj' then 20 
              When 'Mumbai' then 25 
              end
```

Answer (score 21):

I think this is what you're trying to achieve

```
   SELECT * 
   FROM testing
   WHERE (Location = 'Bhuj' AND Age>20) 
        OR (Location = 'Mumbai' AND Age>25)
```

Check [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6120e/5)

**UPDATE:**

Case statement returns a value, you can't have a condition inside it.

Comment: Yes correct. But can't we use `CASE` statement which I shown in example?

Comment: We can use `CASE` in `WHERE` clause. See another answer by podiluska.

Comment: I didn't say you can't use case in where clause. What I say, is that you can't have a condition inside case statement. podiluska's answer is correct if you care about using case statement.